# ¿Cómo realizar un Select con PDO en Postgresql / PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, select

Actualmente estoy probando trabajar con PDO para evitar el SQL Injection pero sinceramente estoy sumamente verde, ya hice mi archivo de conexion a la base de datos por PDO pero no tengo bien claro como puedo hacer una consulta a traves de un select y el resultado mostrarlo en un echo.

Aquí tengo mi archivo de Conexión(pdoconnexpo.php):

```html
<?php

require_once 'pdodatosexpo.php';

$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db;user=$username;password=$password";

try{
 // Crear la conexion a la base de datos postgresql
 $conn2 = new PDO($dsn);

 // Mostrar un mensaje si la conexion es efectiva
 if($conn2){
 echo "Conexión a la base de datos <strong>$db</strong> Exitosa!";
 }
}catch (PDOException $e){
 // Reportar mensaje de error
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Y aqui hago mi consulta y trato de mostrar el resultado, me imagino que el error es de principiante.

```html
<?php
include ('pdoconnectexpo.php');
/*
$query = "SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='luis'";
$result = pg_query($query);
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($result){
echo $row['usuario'];
}else{
  echo "error en la consulta";
}
*/
include ('pdoconnectexpo.php');

$query = 'SELECT usuario FROM "public".usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario';
$registros = $conn2->prepare( $query ); //Preparamos la consulta
$registros->execute( array(":usuario" => $usuario) ); //Le pasamos el valor al marcador, esto es un array por lo que soporta tanto valores requiera la query, separador por coma
$registros = $registros->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); //convirtiendo el resultado en objetos para poder iterar en un ciclo.
$registros[0]->usuario;
foreach ( $registros as $datos){
  echo $datos->usuario;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola, si aun estas a tiempo deberías considerar usar un framework (como laravel, symphony, codeigniter, etc) en lugar de código nativo, te ahorras muchos de estos problemas.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo amigo, pero estamos tratando de hacer un sistema viejo un poco más seguro y evitar posibles ataques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con postgres en tu SQL debes incluir el esquema en tu consulta, si este no tiene un nombre dentro del estándar debe ir entre comillas dobles;

> Dígase que tu esquema tiene un nombre que incluye mayúsculas, guion
>   (-) o espacios.

```
$query = 'SELECT usuario FROM "mi_esquema".usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario ';
```

> Nota que he encerrado el string en comillas simples para poder incluir
>   las dobles dentro de la cadena, también date cuenta que incluí un
>   marcador en la consulta de esta manera preparamos una consulta para
>   evitar la inyección sql.

Luego procedemos a ejecutar la query;

```
    $usuario = 'luis';
    $registros = $mi_conexion->prepare( $query ); //Preparamos la consulta      
    $registros->execute( array(":usuario" => $usuario) ); //Le pasamos el valor al marcador, esto es un array por lo que soporta tanto valores requiera la query, separador por coma
    $registros = $registros->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); //convirtiendo el resultado en objetos para poder iterar en un ciclo.
```

Hasta este punto ya tienes ejecutada tu query y almacenado el resultado como objetos en la variable `$registros`, si deseas acceder unicamente al primer registro lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera;

```
<?= $registros[0]->usuario ?>
```

Ahora si lo que deseas es recorrer todos los registros que existan dentro de este resultado lo logras con un `foreach`;

```
foreach ( $registros as $datos){
  echo $datos->usuario;
}
```

> Nota que he hecho referencia en el foreach al campo el cual devuelte
>   tu query, de tener mas campos puedes hacerlo de la misma manera,
>   ejemplifico;

```
foreach ( $registros as $datos){
      echo $datos->usuario;
      echo $datos->edad;
      echo $datos->peso;
    }
```

Comment: Soy algo nuevo en todo esto, modifiqué el codigo segun tu recomendación y aun así no me imprime nada, podrías por favor decirme donde tengo el error.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz te esta dando algún error ? de ser así agregado para verificarlo.

Comment: No me genera ningun error,solo no me imprime nada en pantalla mas que el mensaje de conexion a la base de datos, comente el codigo inicial y agregue el nuevo para que puedas visualizarlo.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz intenta hacer `var_dump($registros);` al final y dime que obtienes

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente resultado: array(0) { }

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz por lo que veo tu tabla no tiene datos, verifica en tu base de datos.

Comment: Coloque esta consulta directamente en pgadmin SELECT usuario FROM "public".usuarios WHERE usuario='luis' y me arroja el resultado luis y los datos correspondiente a el actualmente tengo 6 registros insertados en esa tabla. Tengo otra duda donde colocaste :usuario debo colocar exactamente eso o el usuario que debo consultar por ejemplo :luis

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz ya vi cual es el problema, es que no le asigne nada a la variable `$usuario` mira ahora mi respuesta la he modificado.

Comment: ¿Ahorra si corre muchas gracias, para trabajar con PDO si o si hay que trabajar orientado a objetos cierto? Y de ser así podrias recomendarme donde aprender a programar orientado a objetos?

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz me alegra mucho y seria de ayuda que marques la respuesta como `respuesta aceptada` por otro lado te puedo recomendar pasarte por el canal de youtube de pildorasinformaticas, ahí aprendí bastante sobre esto.

Comment: Gracias, listo ya lo marque como respuesta aceptada. Saludos.